# Where are expenditures of non-government non-proft organizations in the expedienture approach of calculating GDP?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

We have 3 categories of spenders:

1.Households (except for buying first-hands houses, all their expenditures are counted as consumption)

2.Firms (all their expedintures are counted as investments)

3.The State (All its expedintures are counted as government expidentures)

Non-government non-profit organization also spend their money, but they don't seem to belong to any of these categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend,

To find non-profit organizations (non-government) expenditures within the national accounts for GDP  you can visit the BEA site (www.bea.gov) and go to the national accounts table 1.13.

non-profit organizations is listed as Nonprofit institutions serving households (line # 49).   To attempt to answer your question it would fall between firms and households but more under households.